# Dynamically populating box and text depending on json element

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm new to js and d3 both and struggling really hard to get the result.
I want to create a index like tree and in the corner of the node of that tree dynamically create a rectangle based on a json property as:

[image]

So I want these dark blue coloured rectangle to be generated dynamically for on the tree nodes depending on the `attribute` property from the json file. If any node does not have `attribute` property then it should not create this rectangle. Inside the rectangle is the value of the attribute property. Size of this rectangle should also be dynamic as if i have multiple comma separated properties then rectangle should change its size dynamically. but after spending a lot of effort I'm getting the tree like:

[image]

So I'm not able to create the blue rectangle and the attribute values are added to each node(all attributes overlaped) whether it has attribute or not.

Following is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node rect {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .5;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var jsonData = [
 {
 "name":"Internet Access main",
 "attribute":{" Broadband provider ":"xyz","Broadband id ":" "},
 "type":null,
 "action":"Create Provide",
 "prnt":null,
 "children":[
  {
   "name":"Internet Access plan",
   "attribute":{},
   "type":null,
   "action":"Provide",    
   "prnt":"Internet Access main",
   "children":[]
  },
  {
   "name":"Service Technology",
   "attribute":{"Service Technology ":" XDBL"},
   "type":null,
   "action":"Provide",
   "prnt":"Internet  Access main",
   "children":[]
  },
  {
   "name":"Access",
   "attribute":{},
   "type":null,
   "action":"Provide",
   "prnt":"Internet Access main",
   "children":[]
  },
  {
   "name":"Upload speed Boost",
   "attribute":{},
   "type":null,
   "action":"Provide",
   "prnt":"Internet Access main",
   "children":[]
  },
  {
   "name":"Download Speed Boost",
   "attribute":{},
   "type":null,
   "action":"Provide",
   "prnt":"Internet Access main",
   "children":[]
  },
  {
   "name":"Internet Additional Service",
   "attribute":{},
   "type":null,
   "action":"Provide",
   "prnt":"Internet Access main",
   "children":[
    {
     "name":"My Business Online",
     "attribute":{},
     "type":null,
     "action":"Provide",
     "prnt":"Internet Additional Service",
     "children":[]
    },
    {
     "name":"Mcloude",
     "attribute":{},
     "type":null,
     "action":"Provide",
     "prnt":"Internet Additional Service",
     "children":[]
    },
    {
     "name":"AULA 385",
     "attribute":{},
     "type":null,
     "action":"Provide",
     "prnt":"Internet Additional Service",
     "children":[]
    },
    {
     "name":"Maintenance",
     "attribute":{},"type":null,
     "action":"Provide",
     "prnt":"Internet Additional Service",
     "children":[]
    },
    {
     "name":"MCAfee",
     "attribute":{},
     "type":null,
     "action":"Provide",
     "prnt":"Internet Additional Service",
     "children":[
      {
       "name":"Full Security",
       "attribute":{},
       "type":null,
       "action":"Provide",
       "prnt":"MCAfee",
       "children":[]
      },
      {
       "name":"Antivirus",
       "attribute":{},
       "type":null,
       "action":"Provide",
       "prnt":"MCAfee",
       "children":[]
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
 
]

var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 20},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    barHeight = 20,
 barWidth = 150;

var i = 0,
    duration = 400,
    root;

var tree1 = d3.layout.tree()
    .nodeSize([0, 20]);

<!-- var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal() -->
    <!-- .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; }); -->
 
var diagonal = function elbow(d, i) { 
  return "M" + d.source.y + "," + d.source.x
      + "V" + d.target.x + "H" + d.target.y;
}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root=jsonData[0];
update(root);
console.log(root);

function update(source) {

  // Compute the flattened node list. TODO use d3.layout.hierarchy.
  var nodes = tree1.nodes(root);
  
  console.log(nodes);
  console.log("amit:-- " + nodes.length);

  var height = Math.max(1000, nodes.length * barHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  d3.select("svg")//.transition()
      //.duration(duration)
      .attr("height", height);

  // Compute the "layout".
  nodes.forEach(function(n, i) {
    //n.x = i * barHeight;
 n.x = i * 40;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .style("opacity", 1e-6);

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  nodeEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("y", -barHeight / 2)
      .attr("height", barHeight)
      .attr("width", barWidth)
   .attr("rx", 5)
   .attr("ry", 5)
      .style("fill", color);

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", 3.5)
      .attr("dx", 5.5)
      .text(function(d) { console.log(d.attribute);return d.name; });
   
  
   
 nodes.forEach(function(n){
 if(JSON.stringify(n.attribute)!="{}"){  
  var str= JSON.stringify(n.attribute);
  var str1 = str.substr(1, str.length-2);  
  var attrArr = str1.split(',');
  attrArr.forEach(function(d, i){
   var newStr= d.split(":");
   console.log(newStr[0].substr(1,newStr[0].length-2) + "= " + newStr[1].substr(1, newStr[1].length-2));
   nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("dy", i*10 +15)
    .attr("dx", 20)
    .text(function(d) { return newStr[0].substr(1,newStr[0].length-2) + "= " + newStr[1].substr(1, newStr[1].length-2); });
  });
 }else{
  
 }
 });

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  nodeEnter.transition()
      .duration(duration)//Note: It tells the duration of tree to be visible when we load the page. More duration more time will ti take
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(tree1.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link");
      
  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      //.duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

}

function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}

</script>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: inside your update function: `// Compute the flattened node list. TODO use d3.layout.hierarchy.
  var nodes = tree1.nodes(root);` did you mean: `// Compute the flattened node list. TODO use d3.layout.hierarchy.
  var nodes = tree1.nodes(source);`

Comment: Yes it means the same you can write `var nodes = tree1.nodes(source);`